# How to pass variable php to javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to pass the variable from php to javascript therefore i create code like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<?PHP

 echo "<h2><a style=\"font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif\" class=\"dummy-media-object\"><p id=\"example2\"><font face='Raleway' size=\"6\">http://examle.com</font></p>";
?>
<div id="article"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: document.getElementById("example2"),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        var markup = data.parse.text["*"];
        var i = $('<div></div>').html(markup);

        // remove links as they will not work
        i.find('a').each(function() { $(this).replaceWith($(this).html()); });

        // remove any references
        i.find('sup').remove();

        // remove cite error
        i.find('.mw-ext-cite-error').remove();

        $('#article').html($(i).find('p'));



        },
        error: function (errorMessage) {
        }
    });    

    });




</script>
<h1>
</h1>




</body>
</html>
```

in here the  document.getElementById("example2") will be the pass the variable but in this case this is not happening. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: document.getElementById("example2").innerHTML will work better - especially when you remove the deprecated font tag and add it as a style to the P

Comment: `url: document.getElementById("example2"),` How on Earth is that supposed to work?You're passing a DOM object, therefore the Ajax request should fail. This might be `url: document.getElementById("example").value` or .innerHTML

Comment: not working ..i try this also and id is "example2" not "example"

Comment: What value you want in `url`? Where is `PHP` variable?

Comment: If my comment did not work, how come you accepted an answer that uses my comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<?php echo "<h2><a style=\"font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif\" class='dummy-media-object'><font face='Raleway' size='6'><p id='example2'>http://examle.com</p></font></a></h2>";?> // change in formatting
<div id="article"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: document.getElementById("example2").innerHTML,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        var markup = data.parse.text["*"];
        var i = $('<div></div>').html(markup);

        // remove links as they will not work
        i.find('a').each(function() { $(this).replaceWith($(this).html()); });

        // remove any references
        i.find('sup').remove();

        // remove cite error
        i.find('.mw-ext-cite-error').remove();

        $('#article').html($(i).find('p'));



        },
        error: function (errorMessage) {
        }
    });    

    });

</script>
<h1>
</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This answer is not adding anything to the question. It is more or less a copy of my comment.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that it is not working is because you have no DOM element with an `id` of `example2`. There are several different ways you can emit this element.

```
<?php echo "<span id='example2'>$somevalue</span> ?> // accessed by
document.getElementById("example2")
```

or you can emit it directly in your javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    <?php echo "var example2Value = $somevalue ?>
</script>
```

or you can create a hidden input to hold your variable

```
<?php echo "<input id='example2' type='hidden' value='$somevalue' /> ?> // accessed by
document.getElementById("example2").value
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for the echo nor the font tag. You use jQuery so access it using the .text() method.

```
<h2 style="font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif">
<a class="dummy-media-object"><p id="example2">http://examle.com</p></a>
<div id="article"></div>
<h1></h1>
```

using this script - note the `$("#example2").text()`

I am not convinced you want JSON since you treat the result as it it is HTML
If example.com is NOT the same server as the script, you will not be able to do what you want due to cross domain access violations unless you can add CORS

```
$(function () {
    $.get($("#example2").text(),function (data) {
      var $i = $('<div></div>').html(data);
      // remove links as they will not work
      $i.find('a').each(function () {
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
      });
      // remove any references
      $i.find('sup').remove();
      // remove cite error
      $i.find('.mw-ext-cite-error').remove();
      $('#article').html($i.find('p'));
   });
});
```

Comment: Please see update. I am pretty sure you have cross domain issues

Answer (score -1):

To pass a php variable to javascript, you can simply do that :

```
<?php 
    $url = "http://examle.com"; 
?>
<script>
    var url = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($url); ?>);
    alert(url) //Will alert "http://examle.com"
</script>
```

Comment: I edited my post to show you a PHP variable transfert to javascript